# How to replace Mutiple Timers with TweenLite delayedCall or ENTER_FRAME event?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, flash-cs6, gsap

Hey everyone so I have a lot of timers in my game to be specific around 8 timers. They all control different Movie clip objects that appear on the stage at different times. I also change the timers in my difficulty update function. Now I have read a lot to understand that Timers do cause lag and decrease the performance. I am creating this game using AS3 Adobe AIR for Android devices. My game seems to freeze for half a second every second which I believe is do to the timers as well as the garbage collector. Either way I was wondering if I remove all these timers and instead replace them with TweenLite `TweenLite.delayedCall`funcion if it would dramatically increase performance. I Have tried this on one of my old timers that i removed and replaced with the tweenlite function and it seems to be working just fine but not sure if this is the correct way of doing it here is how i have it set up in my constructor:

```
TweenLite.delayedCall(6.0, addWatch);
```

and the `addWatch` function:

```
private function addWatch():void 
    {
        TweenLite.delayedCall(6.0, addWatchTimer);
        var newWatch:mcWatchTimer = new mcWatchTimer();
        stage.addChild(newWatch);
        aWatchTimerArray.push(newWatch);

        //Start screen sound
        watchSoundChannel;
        watchSound = new watch();
        watchSoundChannel = watchSound.play(0, 9999);
    }
```

this seems to loop it without me having to attach an ENTER_FRAME Eveent listener to it. But not sure if this would be wise since I want to be able to change the `delayedCall` in my difficulty update to a faster time interval.

Any feedback on the situation would be appreciated. Hope I made enough sense.

Comment: I don't remember but TweenLite itself may use timers.

Comment: 8 timers is really not a lot, they probably are not the cause of your lag. Publishing AIR for Android require ultra precise optimization since CPUs can be very weak.

Comment: I kind of noticed some lag mainly during the hitTesting. Yeah I understand I am publishing the game using the devices GPU. But still lag seems to occur. I might have a memory leak somewhere now that I think about it. Sometimes during the game i see the memory keep increasing and increasing. Ill have to try and figure out what could be going on if its not really the timers. Thanks though for the info